# How to use ng-route with resolve without ng-view in template?

Tags: angularjs

I have AngularJS JavaScript code with a routing:

```
.when("/home/:id", {
                        templateUrl: " ",
                        controller: "TestController",
                        resolve: {
                            message: function(app, helpers, $route){
                                console.log($route);

                                return app.get({
                                    user: 533,
                                    id: 2

                                }).then(function (response) {
                                    console.log($route);
                                    return helpers.toArray(response.app);
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

My HTML link as:

```
<a href="#/home/1">Click</a>
```

Also my `TestController` is:

```
.controller('TestController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', 'message', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, message) {
            $scope.appointments = message;
}])
```

When I try to get `$route` in `resolve` like as:

`console.log($route);`

I get nothing.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you are trying to do. It doesn't make sense to have a route with no template. Also you should probably be inspecting `$routeParams` in your resolve. The part about no `ng-view` also doesn't make sense

Comment: It sounds like you want a service, not a route doing all of this. Why not just call `someService.getAppointments(ID_here).then(function (response) { /* your response */ });`

Comment: I try to call AJAX when I open page with URL, but I dont get params from routing inside `resolve`

Comment: `I dont use ng-view for this routing`. I need to detect URL and do AJAX request

Comment: what you are describing isn't how the framework is designed to operate.